# Instagram Live Feed Embeded in HTML Webpage?

Tags: instagram

I am new to web development and am currently building a new website. My skills are currently limited to HTML and CSS.

I would like to know if there is a way to have a page on my site that kind of replicates my Intagram account. Every time I upload a new image to Instagram I would like my web page feed to automatically update and show the new image in the feed along with the previous images in my IG feed.

Is there a plugin I can use? I don't want to have to pay for a widget.

Maybe there is a simple piece of JavaScript I can just copy and paste and then add my IG username or something?

I would like the finished page to display something like this: http://www.zetterbluntdesign.com/instagram

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Take small steps.

Learn Javascript, then proceed on to learning some JS library for building UIs and once your are done with that. Go on to learn backend, databases will help you persist the images you want to display.